# Menu toggleClass open doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm just trying to simply using toggleClass to trigger a class of .open on a closed menu. Here's an image of what it should look like before and after: [image: BEFOREAFTER]

So I know this is pretty simple as I've made it work before, but I can't figure out why it won't work now.

My HTML is like this:

```
<div id="nav">
     <h1>SAKURA GARAGE</h1>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="button" class="menu_toggle_container">
     <span class="menu_toggle"></span>
     </a>
     <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#" title="products">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="about">About</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
#nav{
background-color:black;
position:absolute;
z-index:115;
top:0;
padding:18px 0 18px 25px;
@include span-columns(12);
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    h1{
    @include span-columns(5);
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    }

    .menu{
    height:0em;
    max-height:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .open{
    height:10em;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $(".menu").toggleClass(".open");
});
```

And here's a live version:[Live Example](http://hellothisis.cc/sg/index.html)

I have a hamburger icon that when clicked, animates to change to an x. I found the code online and it works fine, but I'm not sure if that's what's messing with the toggle class. When I inspect element, I can see the class of .open being added and removed, but nothing changes.

Hopefully this isn't toooo simple of a solution...Thanks for reading though!

Comment: Try remove the . (period) before the "open" in `toggleClass`. Should look like `$(".menu").toggleClass("open");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `.` in the `toggleClass` method:

```
$(".menu").toggleClass("open");
```

Also, your CSS is a little off. You have an extra closing `}` after the `.open` class. Is this a typo on Stack Overflow? The closing `}` should be after the `#nav` properties have been declared.

Something like this:

```
#nav{
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:115;
  top:0;
  padding:18px 0 18px 25px;
  @include span-columns(12); /* not sure what this does? */
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

h1{
  @include span-columns(5); /* not sure what this does? */
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.menu{
  height:0em;
  max-height:0%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.open{
  height:10em;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks! I fixed that but it still doesn't take on the .open properties when toggled...

Comment: @user2056708 Have added to answer. What is the `@include` in your CSS. Is this [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: Yes it's Sass and bourbon neat for columns! So the h1, .menu, and .open are nested in #nav

Comment: But what properties are missing when you toggle the dropdown ?

Comment: @user2056708 I take it that this is the pre-compiled CSS? where is the JavaScript? Is it in an external file? I can't see it on your site...

Comment: The menu has an initial property of height:0 em / max-height 0%. When I toggle the drop down and add class of .open, I was hoping it would take over the properties of "height:10 em / max-height: 100%", and the transitions would create the dropdown action.

Comment: Oh yes, the snippet is form the .scss file. The only js file I have is for the fullpage scroll, would you need that?

Comment: @user2056708 I'm afraid to say that you are ***still*** toggling `.open` on your site. The class `.open` is being added to your `<ul>` on the button click as expected. Please update the [Live Example](http://hellothisis.cc/sg/index.html). ***Again***, you should be toggling `open`, not `.open`...

Comment: Ah! Embarrassing! I edited a duplicate file I was working on. It works now. Thank you both so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
```

Instead of this

```
  $(".menu").toggleClass(".open");
```

You do not need a dot as a prefix as the method already assumes its argument to be a class.

Comment: Thank you!! I fixed that but it still doesn't take on the .open properties when toggled...

Comment: Right click on Browser>Inspect Element >Then go to console tap and look there for error related to javascript and jquery.